# How to edit fields in grid popup that are not part of grid columns?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I need to prepare grid with limited number of columns and only when grid row is edited (in popup) it should contain additional fields to edit.

How to edit fields in grid popup that are not part of grid columns?

Comment: Set your datasource to a model that has all the fields you want to display or edit. You can pick the columns to display in the columns collection of the grid, but you can edit anything in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a template for the popup, check [this](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/editable.template):

```
<script id="popup-editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <h3>Edit Person</h3>
  <p>
    <label>Name:<input name="name" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Age: <input data-role="numerictextbox" name="age" /></label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Active: <input type="checkbox" # if (data.active) { #checked="checked"# } #>
  </p>
</script>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    { command: "edit" }
  ],
  dataSource: {
   data: [
    { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, active: false },
    { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33, active: true }
   ],
   schema:{
    model: {
     id: "id",
     fields: {
       age: { type: "number"}
     }
    }
   }
  },
  editable: {
    mode: "popup",
    template: kendo.template($("#popup-editor").html())
  }
});
</script>
```

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AdoVAXAf)

Comment: Is it possible to seek for additional data for grid row to edit only if user want to edit certain row? In other words: grid is defined with datasource with f.e. 4 fields, but with edit popup i want to retrieve 50 more fields for this row to edit.

Comment: @Sruj where is that *additional data* ?

Comment: On server, I can retireve that in json. I have created new topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966712/how-to-retrieve-additional-data-for-grid-row-to-edit-only-if-user-want-to-edit-c