# How to retrieve additional data for grid row to edit only if user want to edit certain row?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

How to retrieve additional data for grid row to edit only if user want to edit certain row?

In other words:

- grid is defined with datasource with f.e. 4 fields,
- but with pressing edit row I want popup to retrieve 50 more fields for this row,
- BUT after pressing *update* I want grid to show updated data (with this 4 fields)

In other words:

- basic data for datasource for grid contain 4 fields/colums
- after clicking edit for row this datasource adds more fields to datasource for edit row.

I know I can at start retrieve all 54 fields and show only 4 of them in the grid and all of them in edit popup, but this might cause perfomance problem.

Comment: What kind of performance issues you think it could have? I think the best way is indeed retrieving all data at once. The dataSource's size should not be a problem. I had developed grids with huge data and the only problem I had is if the grid has to many rows, like 1000+ or something. Also, you could perform an ajax request in the `beforeEdit` event but the built-in popup doesn't waits for it, you would have to create your own custom popup. Unless you try to use `async: false` in the jquery ajax, but I never tried it, can't tell you.

Comment: performance issues related to sql that prepare data for datasource. It's heavy to prepare additional data for one row and with thousand of rows thats a problem.

Comment: Well, you can try an async request in the [`beforeEdit`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/beforeedit) event, and set the data to the `model`. Not sure if that works tho.

Comment: That's crazy, 300 fields is nothing let alone 54. You are using paging correct?

Comment: @SteveGreene the point is: sql query for additional data is very complicated and very heavy, so it can only be done for one row. (that is what sql guy says)